# About phase unwrapping

Tags: sampling, frequency, phase, time-frequency, frequency-modulation

I am not too familiar with phase-related problems so I need some suggestions or corrections in a problem that might be an old but easy one. Here is my problem: given a complex signal:
$$y(t) = e^{j\phi(t)}$$
where $\phi(t)$ is the instantaneous phase. Now we have the observations $y(t)$. Can we somehow reconstruct $\phi(t)$?

I understand the phase will be wrapped into $-\pi$ to $\pi$ when we calculate the phase from $y(t)$. For example, let $\phi(t) = 130t+150t^2 + 0.2, t\in[0,1]$ with a sampling frequency $f = 512$. When I try to reconstruct the phase from $y(t)$ using **unwrap(angle(y(t)))** in Matlab, i.e., the unwrapped phase, the result is shown in the following figure:

[image: Phase comparison]

The second example is that $\phi(t) = 450t-100t^3 + 0.2, t\in[0,1]$. The result is

[image]

The reconstructed phases are different from the original ones. Does this mean that the phase cannot be uniquely reconstructed? Could anyone show me some explanations or suggestions? Thank you!

Edit: the code is as follows.

```
clear all 
clc
N = 512;
t = (0:N-1)/N;
% phi = (130*t + 150*t.^2) + 0.2;
phi = (450*t - 100*t.^3) + 0.2;
s = exp(2*pi*1i*phi);
phase_rcst = unwrap(angle(s))/(2*pi);
figure
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(phi)
title('Phase of the original signal')
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(phase_rcst)
title('Unwrapped phase')
```

Comment: Could you post your code? I'm not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MattL. The code has been added. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from sampling the phase. For the given phase function, the changes in the phase from one value $t_i$ to the next one $t_{i+1}$ can become too large, so phase unwrapping will not work properly. If you simply removed the factor $2\pi$ in the exponent, the problem would be solved already (note that the factor shouldn't be there anyway according to definition of $y(t)$ in your first formula):

`s = exp(1i*phi);`

If you want to keep the factor $2\pi$, then use more sampling points.

Comment: This is correct. More precisely, as the phase change from one value to the next becomes larger than $\pi$, the phase unwrapping stops working properly. 

Imagine two consecutive phase values are 0, and $\pi+0.1$. The phase difference is thus $\pi+0.1$. When the phases are wrapped to the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, these consecutive phase values become $0$ and $-\pi + 0.1$. The phase difference is now $-\pi+0.1$, a negative value. This is why your unwrapped phase plots change direction. The change happens at the time step where the original phase difference becomes larger than $\pi$.